# I am trying here to make sphere using reactJS + threeJS

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Here i am trying to make sphere usign threejs in react project and it is compiled successfully i am not getting any errors in the console either but in the outpput i am getting an only black canvas not sphere so i anybody can help that would be great.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
// import './Three.css';
import * as THREE from 'three';

const Three = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Scene
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create a sphere shape
    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 64, 32);
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: "#00ff83",
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Lights
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
    light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
    scene.add(light);

    // Camera
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 800/600);
    camera.position.z = 20;
    scene.add(camera);

    // Renererd
    // const canvas = new document.querySelector('.webgl');
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvasRef.current || undefined});
    renderer.setSize(800, 600);
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures that this effect runs once when the component mounts

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} className='webgl'></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Three;
```

Comment: If you are using three.js for the first time and willing to work on a react project, you definitely should use react-three-fiber. That one is way easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

First, your sphere is black because there is not enough light in your scene, your background is black either, so you can't see the sphere.

Add:

```
const al = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(al);
```

Secondly, the radius of your sphere is much too large compared to the camera props.

Change to:

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 32);
```

If you want to check the size of your current sphere and its radius, you can first add light and change color, then you will see that it will *spread* over the entire canvas.

And finally place the animation loop.

```
const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
animate();
```

And as the colleague above mentioned, it is much *cleaner* to use R3F if you don't want vanilla 3js.